# Dart/Flutter Yield state after timer

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using `flutter_bloc` and I am not sure how to yield state from within a callback.
Am trying to start timer and return a new state after a pause. Reason I am using a timer is to get the ability to cancel previous timer so it always returns a new state after an idle state.

```
@override
  Stream<VerseState> mapEventToState(
    VerseEvent event,
  ) async* {
if (event is ABCEvent) {
Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
        print("Here");
        _onTimerEnd(); // adding yield here returns an error.
      })
}

Stream<XYZState> _onTimerEnd() async* {
    print("Yielding a state");
    yield myNewState();
  }
```

I can see that the code is getting inside the timer callback as I can see the print statements in the callback but not in the `timerEnd()` method.

Comment: Just had to add another event after timer has run or cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State should be yielded by the stream used in bloc that you are current working on. Like

> mapEventToState

Comment: Yes I am using `mapEventToState` but I cannot yield after timer is done, I can yield only by using await which does not work for me here.

Comment: then you should trigger an event

Comment: Just to close this out, I ended up using the event, for some reason I completely overlooked this.